# set env variable when Running jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have this variable defined on my `main.ts`

```
const mockMode = process.env.MOCK_MODE;
```

I just create a test and set this variable to true, but on the main does not get `'true'`, but `'false'`

```
describe('onBook', () => {

    // Arrange
     const mockMode = "true";
     ...
```

Comment: Use `globals` option from jest config. Follow this link: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globals-object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the value of `process.env.MOCK_MODE` directly within the unit test case and restore it to original value at the end.

E.g.

`main.ts`:

```js
export function main() {
  const mockMode = process.env.MOCK_MODE;
  return mockMode;
}
```

`main.test.ts`:

```js
import { main } from './main';

describe('main', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const original = process.env.MOCK_MODE;
    process.env.MOCK_MODE = 'true';
    const actual = main();
    expect(actual).toBe('true');
    process.env.MOCK_MODE = original;
  });
  it('should restore MOCK_MODE', () => {
    expect(process.env.MOCK_MODE).toBe('undefined');
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59319610/main.test.ts (14.207s)
  main
    ✓ should pass (7ms)
    ✓ should restore MOCK_MODE (1ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        16.293s
```

Comment: How this will be utilized when running tests in parallel? Is the `process.env` also sandboxed for each tests?

Comment: This doesn't work if the test fails. You should use `afterEach` for this.