# How to test environment variables before all tests and fail if an env is undefined?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, environment-variables, es6-modules

Is there a way to test `env` before all tests and not proceed if an `env` is `undefined`? I initially tried to define my `dotenv` in *package.json*:

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "roots": [
      "__tests__",
      "bin",
      "src"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/__tests__/env-setup.js"
    ],
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/docs",
      "<rootDir>/__tests__/files",
      "<rootDir>/__tests__/helpers",
      "<rootDir>/__tests__/env-setup"
    ]
  },
```

and after reading [Test process.env with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58953365/1952287) but that didn't work so wrote my test as:

file `/__tests__/env.test.js`:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const envObj = {
  foo: process.env.FOO,
  bar: process.env.BAR,
}

describe('env tests', () => {
  Object.keys(envObj).map((k, i) => {
    it(`testing ${Object.keys(envObj)[i]}`, () => {
      expect(envObj[k]).toBeDefined()
      if (envObj[k] === undefined) new Error(`Missing env variable for "${Object.keys(envObj)[i]}"`)
    })
  })
})
```

and while this will error out after the test is still proceeds with all tests. After my research, I did find [`beforeAll`](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#beforeallfn-timeout) and wrote:

file `/__tests__/env.index.js`:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const envObj = {
  foo: process.env.FOO,
  bar: process.env.BAR,
}

beforeAll(() => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    Object.keys(envObj).map((k, i) => {
      if (envObj[k] === undefined)
        rej(new Error(`Missing env variable for "${Object.keys(envObj)[i]}"`))
    })
    res()
  })
})
```

but then my issue is this has to be before every file and it still runs further tests. Further research to see if this has been asked I've read through:

- [how to reset module imported between tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989643/how-to-reset-module-imported-between-tests)
- [How do I mock `.env` variables in Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68643820/how-do-i-mock-env-variables-in-jest)
- [Using .env files for unit testing with jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259025/using-env-files-for-unit-testing-with-jest)
- [How can I mock a env.dev.js file using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71489696/how-can-i-mock-a-env-dev-js-file-using-jest)
- [set env variable when Running jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59319610/set-env-variable-when-running-jest)
- [Jest test not reading environment variables with dotenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61781150/jest-test-not-reading-environment-variables-with-dotenv)
- [Environment variables undefined in NextJS when running Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934104/environment-variables-undefined-in-nextjs-when-running-jest)
- [Using environment variables in Node and Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72592581/using-environment-variables-in-node-and-jest)

In Jest is there a way to run an env test before all tests and the first instance a variable is `undefined` it will stop any further tests?